# SoundPool streamid

Tags: android, soundpool

So I have soundpool OnLoadCompleteListener which has this code mStreamId = soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f); and i have 2 buttons that will play diffrent soundpools.I use mStreamId to stop soundpool.My problem is when i click first button and it plays sound and i click the second button it will stop the sound of first button. Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Settings {
        SoundPool mSoundPool;
        int mSoundId;
        int mStreamId = 0;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
            mSoundPool
                    .setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool,
                                int sampleId, int status) {
                            mStreamId = soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
}
                });

    }
//OnClick
public void button1(View view) {
        if (mStreamId != 0) {
            mSoundPool.stop(mStreamId);
        }

        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), et1.getText()
                .toString());
        mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(path, 1);
    }
public void button2(View view) {
        if (mStreamId != 0) {
            mSoundPool.stop(mStreamId);
        }

        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), et2.getText()
                .toString());
        mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(path, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Save soundId and streamId separate.

onLoadComplete is called after load, so when you press button2, the streamId is the id for the sound played by button1.

Comment: what do you mean by save soundid and streamid seprate?

Comment: like this: int soundId1, soundId2, streamId1, streamId2.

Comment: so i have modifed that code a little bit just to get string everytime when button is clicked and it doesnt work.. heres link http://pastebin.com/M7gYyaFD

Comment: it will leak data, because you never unload ... and sound will not play, because every time it want to play, the data do not load complete. Use more two button for load better.

Comment: or use change check for load, if text changed, load it, not load every time.